# How to add Connect string in dotnet in mac

Tags: c#, .net, rest

```
 dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.412
 Commit:    ee124f7fe1

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  13.4
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.13-arm64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.412/
```

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ConsoleApp2.Data
{
    public class BookStoreContext:DbContext
    {
        public BookStoreContext(DbContextOptions<BookStoreContext> options):
            base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Books> Books { get; set;}

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost,3306;Database=BookstoreApi;user=root;Password=Rahul@2018; Persist security Info = True;");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

```
dotnet ef migrations  //worked fine
```

```
dotnet ef  database update  // but is is throwing error.
```

System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryProcessHeader()
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable, Boolean& fedAuthRequired)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover,.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Internal connection fatal error.

Please anyone help why i am getting `Internal connection fatal error.` .

Comment: Hello @rahulyadav
Are you using docker to host your database?

Comment: @CaioRagazzi No , using local MySQL DB